# Witness client failed to register with Witness Server

Tags: windows, samba

I am having a 2 node Windows cluster. On the event logs, I get the following error which freezes my cluster access every now and then.

> Witness Client failed to register with Witness Server FILESHARE2 for notification on NetName \fileshare with error (The parameter is incorrect.)

Is there any posisbility to disable the Witnessclient?

The cluster is being accessed by several other servers.

Cluster configured on Windows Server 2012R2. Server nodes accessing Cluster also on Windows Server 2012R2.

What is the possible fix for the issue here?

`Get-SmbWitnessClient` yields an empty output on both the cluster and other nodes.